# Select2 + Django: set preferred list items

Tags: python, django, jquery-select2, django-countries

I use select2][1](https://select2.github.io/) with [django-countries](https://github.com/SmileyChris/django-countries) in order to give the user a dropdown of possible countries. I now would like to either (1) split the dropdown or (2) rearrange the order of the items/countries, i.e.:

Currently I get an alphabetically ordered list:

```
- select country
  - Afghanistan
  - Albania
  - Algeria
  ...
  - Kenya
  ...
  - Zimbabwe
```

What I would like is:
(1)

```
- select country
  - Germany
  - Austria
  - Switzerland
  ---------------------------
  - Afghanistan
  - Albania
  - Algeria
  ...
  - Kenya
  ...
  - Zimbabwe
```

or (2)

```
- select country
  - Germany
  - Austria
  - Switzerland
  - Afghanistan
  - Albania
  - Algeria
  ...
  - Kenya
  ...
  - Zimbabwe
```

This is my js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#id_nationality").select2({
        default: 'Germany',
        placeholder: 'select country'
    });
});
```

I use crispy-forms for form rendering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, as django-countries has this function included.

See [this](https://github.com/SmileyChris/django-countries#show-certain-countries-first).

Comment: Hi! Did you manage to use this select using the COUNTRIES_FIRST _BREAK   and passing `required` to the select element?